# setOn"Fast"Click - JavaFx

Tags: javafx, onclick, onclicklistener

I have a **Button** that I can move it from the screen, when clicking it has an action. The problem is, when I do Drag'n Drop the click event is called when I release the mouse on, I tried it:

`setOnMouseClicked`
`setOnAction`
`setOnMousePressed`

How can I do to just call the click function when it is a quick click, something like Android times that can differentiate because we have `setOnLongClick`, so differentiated when I have doing Drag'n Drop and when I really want to click?

Ex:

To move, do:

```
button.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
     //code move
});
```

To eventClick:

```
button.setOnMouseClicked/ Action / MousePressed (e -> {
    //call method
});
```

But when I drop it, it calls setOnMouseClicked / Action / MousePressed, what I want is for it to just call in case I give a quick click, when I drop the drag'n drop do not call.

[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] demonstrating the issue?

Comment: @Slaw Take a look now

Comment: @Slaw Now look at the GIF to get clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to keep track of whether or not the `Button` was dragged; if not, only then execute the code in the `onAction` handler. Here's an example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

  private Point2D origin;
  private boolean wasDragged;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button button = new Button("Drag me!");
    button.setOnAction(this::onAction);
    button.setOnMousePressed(this::onMousePressed);
    button.setOnMouseDragged(this::onMouseDragged);
    button.setOnMouseReleased(this::onMouseReleased);

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(button), 800, 600));
    primaryStage.show();
  }

  private void onAction(ActionEvent event) {
    event.consume();

    if (!wasDragged) {
      System.out.println("onAction");
    }
  }

  private void onMousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
    event.consume();
    origin = new Point2D(event.getX(), event.getY());

    System.out.println("onMousePressed");
  }

  private void onMouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
    event.consume();
    wasDragged = true;

    Button source = (Button) event.getSource();
    source.setTranslateX(source.getTranslateX() + event.getX() - origin.getX());
    source.setTranslateY(source.getTranslateY() + event.getY() - origin.getY());
  }

  private void onMouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
    event.consume();
    origin = null;
    wasDragged = false;

    System.out.println("onMouseReleased");
    System.out.println();
  }

}
```

Unfortunately, I can't find documentation guaranteeing the `onAction` handler is always called before the `onMouseReleased` handler, but this worked on both Java 8u202 and JavaFX 11.0.2 when I tried it.